# PHP Invoices change start day of the week -2 days

Tags: php, woocommerce, days, orders, invoices

I have a question im busy with an invoice system and have the following problem:
We want to send the invoices every saterday and each week.

So our week is from saterday till friday.

Now is our output like this:

```
Order:3869
Weeknr:2017-07
Weektime:2017-02-17 16:11:54
EndDate:2017-02-18

Weektime String:1487347914
EndDate String:1487376000

Order:3874
Weeknr:2017-07
Weektime:2017-02-19 14:52:57
EndDate:2017-02-18

Weektime String:1487515977
EndDate String:1487376000
```

Here you see Order: 3874, this needs to be Weeknr: 2017-08

This is my loop:

```
foreach( $orders as $order){
    if($order->post->post_parent != 0){
        $endDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last saturday')));
        $week = date('Y-W', strtotime($order->post->post_date));
        $weektime = strtotime($order->post->post_date);

if($weektime > $eindDatum){
                continue;
            }
    }
```

Now i can't find how i can see if our week starts at monday in PHP, if thats true how can i change weektime -2 days.

Sorry for my poor explanation in bad english but I hope someone can help me

O this is my pre of the orders like the example:

```
    echo '<pre>';
        echo 'Order:'.print_r($order->post->ID,true).'<br>';
        echo 'Weeknr:'.print_r($week,true).'<br>';
        echo 'Weektime:'.print_r($order->post->post_date,true).'<br>';
        echo 'EindDatum:'.print_r(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last saturday')),true).'<br><br>';
        echo 'Weektime String:'.print_r($weektime,true).'<br>';
        echo 'EindDatum String:'.print_r($eindDatum,true).'<br>';
    echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php DateTime object in association with modify method to move a portion of time on a date.

Example

`$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$date->modify('-2 day');`

Comment: Than i get an output like: "Weeknr:1970-01"

Comment: Probably because you didn't converted it to DateTime object correctly